# What is the fastest way to detect a mobile browser

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I know there is many questions about what is the best way to detect a mobile browser but my problem is another. I have a wordpress website and i want to know what is the fastes way to detect a mobile browser, i want a method that doesn't slow down my page speed during user navigation.

Comment: Have you performance-tested the best-practice solutions and decided they're too slow?  If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: Not yet. I'm asking if someone did that. I learned there are several ways: php code, apache, javascript but my concern is about page speed.